# True or False: U= rowspace(A), V= columnspace(A), and W= nullspace(A)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$
        A= \begin{pmatrix}
        -1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
        1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
        0 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 4 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

True or False

W⊆$R^3$

I know that W⊆$R^5$ not $R^3$ but I am not sure how we came up with $R^5$

Comment: You could have a better title of the post and move the definitions down to the body of your question.

Answer (score 0):

A $3\times 5$ matrix describes a linear map from $K^5$ to $K^3$, so the kernel of this map is contained in $K^5$ ($K$ denotes the base field).